# How to prevent multiple clicks in div in-out animation

Tags: jquery

I want to move div in and out on click of it. I just animate the div like

```
<head>
    <title>Title</title>

     <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        .slide-out-div {
            position:relative;
            background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #F2F2F2;
            border: 2px solid #29216D;
            color: #666666;
            font-size: 14px;
            padding: 20px;
            width: 250px;
            left: -210px; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
     <div class="slide-out-div">
         <form>
             <a class="handle" href="http://link-for-non-js-users">SEARCH</a>
             <button id="myButton" type="submit" />
         </form>
     </div>
</body>
```

Here is the script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var visible = 0;
    $(".slide-out-div").click(function() {
        var $div = $(this);
        if (visible == 0) {
            $div.animate({left: "10px"}, "slow");
            visible = 1;
        } else {
            $div.animate({left: "-210px"}, "slow");
            visible = 0;
        }      
    });
}); //end of  $(document).ready(fn)
```

First i want to ask is my script ok? It is working but it doesn't mean it is efficient. Second when it is coming to or gone from then if user clicks on multiple times then i think the animation goes to animation queue and my div continuously animate.
I want that when user click on first time then the animation runs. Multiple clicks don't run. How can i prevent user multiple clicks?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible short solution:

```
$(".slide-out-div").click(function() {
    var $div = $(this);
    $div.not(":animated").animate({
        left: $div.position().left == -210 ? 10 : -210
    }, "slow");
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/rXW9D/

Comment: I question i want to ask that my div has left of -210px. But when i use `animate(left: "10px")`, then it doesn't work like `-210 + 10 = -200`. It moves the element as it has it left position 0. Am i right?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`.stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) function to end the current animation, and then begin the new one, on each subsequent click. This wouldn't prevent multiple clicks, but could be used to prevent multiple queued animations.

Alternatively, you could use the [`:animated` selector](http://api.jquery.com/animated-selector/) to check that the element is not currently being animated, and only animate if that is the case.

```
$(".slide-out-div").click(function() {
    var $div = $(this);
    if(!$div.is(':animated')) {
        if (visible == 0) {
            $div.animate({left: "10px"}, "slow");
            visible = 1;
        } else {
            $div.animate({left: "-210px"}, "slow");
            visible = 0;
        }      
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to keep a lock for animating, following should work

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var blockAnimation = false;
    var visible = 0;
    $(".slide-out-div").click(function() {
      if(blockAnimation != true){
        blockAnimation = true;
        var $div = $(this);
        if (visible == 0) {
            $div.animate({left: "10px"}, "slow");
            visible = 1;
        } else {
            $div.animate({left: "-210px"}, "slow");
            visible = 0;
        }  
       }    
    });
});
```